# INSERT IGNORE runs inside TRANSACTION

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

I am in a confusion.
I have a cron job written in PHP to insert values into a table. But some values may already exist in the table. But we are not sure which are they. So I used INSERT IGNORE INTO method to insert my entries like follows,

```
$insertSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `my_procuts` (`product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES " . $valueString . ";";
$insertResult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertSql);
$affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

Where $valueString is the output of a previous for loop. And those are the values to insert. This query works fine. Values are inserting as I expected.
Now,
I want to add a TRANSACTION to this insertion. So I try it like this,

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
$insertSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `my_procuts` (`product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES " . $valueString . ";";
$insertResult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertSql);
$affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
mysqli_commit($conn);
```

Now the query is not working. $affectedRows gives -1 result always. What may the issue I have made.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: show what contains, in `$valueString`

Comment: This may be an artifcact of that some inserted rows are causing (ignored) duplicate key violations.  Check your data.

Comment: What are you using `MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY` for?

Comment: The mistake was mine. I should not use MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY flag in the transaction. Thanks @NigelRen :)